# Changed permissions for www but Apache still doesn't have permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I gave the www group write permissions to a file but Apache still doesn't have write permissions to that file. However, if I give 'Others' write permission to that file (e.g. 0777 permission) Apache gets write permission to that file.
How can I fix this?
I am using Amazon Linux hosted by Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a lot of reasons for that...

1. Did you try to `setenforce 0`?
2. What if `chmod o+w` to that file?

Try that first, it will dismiss first guesses and common problems.

Comment: `sentenforce 0` returns `command not found`. `chmod o+w` grants 0777 permissions which allows Apache to write to that file. However I don't want to grant 0777 permissions to that file for security purposes.

Comment: Not `sentenforce` but `setenforce` - this will turn your SELinux off if it's working (as by default). However, It seems for me that Apache for some reason is not a member of `www` group, otherwise you should be able to access the file with no `o+w`: in your case Apache service matches the `others` section.

Comment: I solved my problem. I opened `httpd.conf` and found that apache uses the User and Group `apache` and not `www`, so I changed the ownership of the file to `apache` using chown.